# Safety of using fixed integer types

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it always safe to use types such as `uint64_t`?

In other words, does the C++ Standards guarantee that this type should be available and it is exactly 64 bit on all platforms?

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer, this one is optional

Comment: You can check the C++17 Draft here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf At page 492 it mentions uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t and uint64_t as optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) on cppreference.com.

Fixed width integers (ex. `uint64_t`) are optional, but if they are available on a platform, their size is guaranteed to be exactly what you expected. The fast (ex. `int_fast32_t`) and least (ex. `int_least32_t`) versions are mandatory.

Comment: There's no underscore between `fast`/`least` and the width in those types.